# Checkout page customer registration is another time not logged

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, registration

`My account` page customer registration is logged but in checkout `Customer registration` is not logged in another time.

**Error :** Display error in invalid username and Password.

**Magento 1.9**

Comment: You mean that :  you can register in my account page and you can't in checkout OR, you are already logged and when you go to checkout you will be not logged ?